# Can't read JSON data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

When opening "http://localhost/uebung/index.html" only the HTML/CSS is shown (Can't read the JSON)

JSON data (works so far):

```
<?php
$array = array(
  array(
    "title" => "Erster Eintrag",
    "description" => "Hier kommt eine Beschreibung hin!",
    "link" => "http://",
    "pubDate" => "02.07.2015"
  ),
  array(
    "title" => "Zweiter Eintrag",
    "description" => "Hier kommt eine Beschreibung hin!",
    "link" => "http://",
    "pubDate" => "02.07.2015"
  )     
);
echo json_encode($array);?>
```

the html file (this file cant read the json file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
      url:'http://localhost/uebung/staticfeed.php',
      type:'POST',
      data: val,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
          $('#feeds').append('<div id="' + key + '">' + val.title + ' ' + val.description + ' ' + val.link + ' ' + val.pubDate + '</div>');
        });

      }
    })
  </script>
  <div id="feeds">dsf
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't read" ?

Answer (score 3):

Write this so you tell your script you are sending JSON

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode($array);?>
```

**OR**

Decode JSON before iterating over it.

```
success: function(data){
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
        ....
```